# How to alternate between two different css animations

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm animating my site navigation in css, and my problem goes like this.

```
 // Html file

       <html> 

        <div class="class-one">
        // some value
        </div>

        </html>

    // Css file

        .class-one {
        width: 100px
        height: 100px
        animation: first-animation paused 7s;
        animation: second-animation paused 7s;
        }
```

I'm controlling the behavior of when each animation plays with jQuery, similar to this.

```
// Javascript file

 $(".class-one").click(function() {

    $(".class-one").css("animation-play-state", "running");

    });
```

My problem is that I cannot specify which animation I want to play, this simply plays the second animation, and not the first. How can I specify which animation that I want to play?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you want to combine both animations into a single animation, or do you want to run them after each other? If it is the latter, you will simply have to combine the keyframes of the animation. Remember in CSS that the last property will override those that come before it—that is why only your second animation is playing.

Comment: @Terry I want to play each animation according to different circumstances. For example:  if element one on page is above 100px, play animation one, if it is not, play animation two.

Comment: How do you want to specify what animation? By user interaction? By toggling a class? That is how I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Terry Yes by user interaction, but I was able to understand it with the help of the user who answered below, thank you though for your reply!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, the second animation property declaration is overriding the first.  You need two classes:

```
// HTML
<body>
  <div class="element-in-question"></div>
</body>


// CSS
.class-one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: first-animation paused 7s;
}

.class-two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: second-animation paused 7s;
}
```

Then using jQuery, you can set the class on your element for the animation you wish to see:

```
// jQuery    
if (condition) {

  // to set first-animation
  $('.element-in-question').addClass('class-one').removeClass('class-two');

} else if (otherCondition) {

  // to set second-animation
  $('.element-in-question').addClass('class-two').removeClass('class-one');
}

// trigger with your existing code
$('.element-in-question').css('animation-play-state', 'running');
```

Comment: Glad to help :)  Just remember--in CSS, if you declare a property more than once (in your case the animation property,) only the last declaration will apply.  The first value for that property is wiped out when the second value is set.  For this reason, it is never a good idea to declare a property more than once in a single class definition!